# Cannot create an editor in razor, System.Windows.Forms is needed

Tags: c#, razor-pages, rider

I have this very basic form in ASP.NET:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        @Html.EditorFor(item => item.Name)
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
    </fieldset>
}
```

When I remove the line `@Html.EditorFor(item => item.Name)` everything works fine. But when I add it I get the following error:

> FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

Why do I need Windows Forms in ASP??? Has anyone else ever experienced the same issue? I created a plain WebApplication with MVC in Rider. Target framework is `netcoreapp3.1` and the language version is `C# 8.0`. If you need further details feel free to ask.

The entire callstack of the error is as follows:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. File not found.
File name: 'System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute._CreateCaObject(RuntimeModule pModule, RuntimeType type, IRuntimeMethodInfo pCtor, Byte** ppBlob, Byte* pEndBlob, Int32* pcNamedArgs)
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.CreateCaObject(RuntimeModule module, RuntimeType type, IRuntimeMethodInfo ctor, IntPtr& blob, IntPtr blobEnd, Int32& namedArgs)
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.AddCustomAttributes(ListBuilder`1& attributes, RuntimeModule decoratedModule, Int32 decoratedMetadataToken, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, ListBuilder`1 derivedAttributes)
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeModule decoratedModule, Int32 decoratedMetadataToken, Int32 pcaCount, RuntimeType attributeFilterType)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.GetCustomAttributes(Type attributeType, Boolean inherit)
   at System.Attribute.InternalGetCustomAttributes(PropertyInfo element, Type type, Boolean inherit)
   at System.Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(MemberInfo element, Boolean inherit)
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttributeExtensions.GetCustomAttributes(MemberInfo element)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ModelAttributes.GetAttributesForProperty(Type containerType, PropertyInfo property, Type modelType)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Metadata.DefaultModelMetadataProvider.CreateSinglePropertyDetails(ModelMetadataIdentity propertyKey, PropertyHelper propertyHelper)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Metadata.DefaultModelMetadataProvider.CreatePropertyDetails(ModelMetadataIdentity key)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Metadata.DefaultModelMetadataProvider.GetMetadataForProperties(Type modelType)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Metadata.DefaultModelMetadata.get_Properties()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ExpressionMetadataProvider.FromLambdaExpression[TModel,TResult](Expression`1 expression, ViewDataDictionary`1 viewData, IModelMetadataProvider metadataProvider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ModelExpressionProvider.CreateModelExpression[TModel,TValue](ViewDataDictionary`1 viewData, Expression`1 expression)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.HtmlHelper`1.GetModelExpression[TResult](Expression`1 expression)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.HtmlHelper`1.EditorFor[TResult](Expression`1 expression, String templateName, String htmlFieldName, Object additionalViewData)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.HtmlHelperEditorExtensions.EditorFor[TModel,TResult](IHtmlHelper`1 htmlHelper, Expression`1 expression)
   at AspNetCore.Views_Home_Edit.ExecuteAsync() in /my/path/Edit.cshtml:line 16
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageCoreAsync(IRazorPage page, ViewContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageAsync(IRazorPage page, ViewContext context, Boolean invokeViewStarts)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderAsync(ViewContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ViewContext viewContext, String contentType, Nullable`1 statusCode)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ViewContext viewContext, String contentType, Nullable`1 statusCode)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext actionContext, IView view, ViewDataDictionary viewData, ITempDataDictionary tempData, String contentType, Nullable`1 statusCode)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewResultExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext context, ViewResult result)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewResult.ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResultFilterAsync>g__Awaited|29_0[TFilter,TFilterAsync](ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext[TFilter,TFilterAsync](State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Comment: What's the call stack of that exception? It can explain all you need.

Comment: I added the callstack of it. I think it says I called EditorFor in a wrong way...

Answer (score 0):

I've found the issue! I imported an enum from a file from another project where `System.Windows.Forms` was imported aswell. Moving the enum elsewhere solved the issue. Now I'm only importing stuff that doesn't import `System.Windows.Forms`.

If you happen to have the same problem: Check your imports, and the imports of your imports.